# ResultSet and BLOB loading

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, blob

I am working on database performance benchmark java application as part of my Master Thesis.
Application starts several threads which performs selects. Then average response time for query is gathered.
Looking on results I have doubts, if BLOB columns are really loaded from database (Almost no difference in response time neither BLOBS in database have 20kB or 100kB or 200kB. Data cannot be cached in RAM, because sumarized BLOBs volume in few times larger, than machine RAM size). I am using MySQL and MySQL Cluster databases.

My selects looks like this:

```
SELECT blob_column FROM tab WHERE <<some conditions on other columns>>
```

And here is part of my application that performs benchmark:

```
    int invokedCommands = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
        try {
            for (int j = 0; j < params.get(i).size(); j++) {
                preparedStatement.setInt(j+1, params.get(i).get(j));
            }
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        invokedCommands++;
    }
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

    synchronized(resultList) {
        resultList.add((double) elapsedTime / invokedCommands);
    }
```

Where `preparedStatement` is prepared select ready to be provided with `WHERE` parameters.
When using method as described above can I be 100% sure, that BLOBs are read from disk and sent to client application?

Comment: Blob is just a pointer to data. You need to fetch contents of blob

Comment: @SamiKorhonen Thank you for your comment. Any advice where I can seek for examples how to do such? Or maybe You can provide one as response to my question?